# selecting grandchild onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some jquery code to select the div which is grandchild of another div having id pageContainer2 on which user clicked and show a alert message with index value. But the code is node working at all, so please see if i am writing the code wrong or is their any other problem.

Following is my html page code with jquery script :

```
<script>
$("div#pageContainer2 div.textLayer div").click(function () {
  // this is the dom element clicked
    var index = $("div").index(this);
    alert("index of div is = " + index);
});
</script>

<div id="pageContainer2" >
<canvas id="page2" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
<div class="textLayer">
<div>......some text here....</div>
<div>......some text here....</div>
<div>......some text here....</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="pageContainer3" >
<canvas id="page3" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
<div class="textLayer">
<div>......some text here....</div>
<div>......some text here....</div>
<div>......some text here....</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".textLayer > div", "#pageContainer2").click(function () {
            var index = $(this).index();
            alert("index of div is = " + index);
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="pageContainer2" >
    <canvas id="page2" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
    <div class="textLayer">
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="pageContainer3" >
    <canvas id="page3" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
    <div class="textLayer">
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cEQ9V/)

Comment: i saw fiddle of all the three answers and your code is returning perfect index value, but on my page the script is not activating by click event don't know why. is it possible that due to presence of another click bound function this script is not running ?? pls reply me ASAP

Comment: although the code works when i put it in some java script function and bind that function to click event listner

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues.

1. You don't appear to be using a `$(document).ready()` event, so the event is bound to no elements, since they're not in the DOM yet.
2. You're trying to find a `div` of `id="textLayer"`, which doesn't exist (you have `class="textLayer"`.
3. You're passing a selector to the `index()` method, this selector is supposed to define the elements among which you want to find the position of this particular object. There is only ever *one* `this` element (even jQuery's `each()` method works with *one* element at a time, from first to last...). So remove that particular selector.

So, corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
    $("div#pageContainer2 div.textLayer div").click(function () {
      // this is the dom element clicked
        var index = $("div").index();
        alert("index of div is = " + index);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dYz35/).​

References:

- [`$(document).ready()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29).
- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [CSS (level 2) selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) and [CSS (level 3) selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: Yes, it does. Try the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dYz35/). If it doesn't work on your site look at the browser error console and see what's happening, or if any errors are reported.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `click` event doesn't binded at all, since `textLayer` is a `class` not `id`, but you selecting by `id`.

Change selector to be:

```
$("div#pageContainer2 div.textLayer div")
```

It's also not clear which index you wan't to show, since what you currently use will return index of specific `div` tag in a whole document. In case you want an index within parent you better use something like:

```
var el = $(this);

var index = $('div', el.parent()).index(this);
// Or
var index = el.prevAll().length;
```

Comment: @hiteshtr, it does, see it live http://jsfiddle.net/b5BLr/ (and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5BLr/1/) with alternative `index` variants within parent

Comment: above html code belongs to pdf.js and it is dynamically generated so is that the reason why the code is not working

Comment: @hiteshtr, Where is nothing wrong with HTML that is generated but the JS you wrote have several issues that was pointed in answers.

Comment: sir i tried all the code answered in this question but non of them is working can i mail you my page so that you can review it properly or else can you provide me other way to perform same task, i will be grateful for your any help

Answer (score 1):

Place you code in `$(document).ready` and change `#textLayer` to `.textLayer`
hiteshtr it is working as you want just check this one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pageContainer2 > .textLayer > div").click(function () {
        // this is the dom element clicked
        var index = $("#pageContainer2 > .textLayer > div").index(this);
        alert("index of div is = " + index);
    });
});
```

Comment: Which magically appeared in other answer couple of minutes before yours?! (couple is ~8 minutes in that case)

Comment: Especially after exactly that code was already present in one of two other answers ;) Common you'll not be dying for that one but it'll surely teach you to read existing answers before posting your own.